# Selenium for firefox gecko driver -Unable to create new remote session on MAC

Tags: macos, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am getting following error when tried to open url in firebox through selenium on Mac machine.

The firefox browser gets launched but doesn't open the url. 
I am able to launch chrome and open the url.
The code is :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/QA/Documents/Selennium_Classes/BrowserExes/geckodriver/");         
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

I get this below mentioned error inside eclipse console, when executing above code.

> 2017-03-29 13:51:07.977 plugin-container[795:54793] *** CFMessagePort:
>   bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port =
>   0x8f3f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname' See
>   /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes. 2017-03-29
>   13:51:07.980 plugin-container[795:54793] *** CFMessagePort:
>   bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port =
>   0x4b1b, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient' See
>   /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes. 2017-03-29
>   13:51:07.980 plugin-container[795:54793] void __CFPasteboardSetup() :
>   Failed to allocate communication port for
>   com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox
>   restrictions Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true,
>   browserName=firefox,
>   moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@6b9651f3,
>   version=, platform=ANY,
>   firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@38bc8ab5}],
>   required capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info: version:
>   '3.2.0', revision: '8c03df6b79', time: '2017-02-23 10:51:31 +0000'
>   System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro.local', ip: ‘xxx.xxx.x.x’, os.name:
>   'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_111' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:293)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:263)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
>     at TestCase.resources.main(resources.java:37)

Comment: I have resolved this issue by downgrading the Geckodriver version to 14.